# Returning error string from abl if no match

Tags: progress-4gl

I'm trying to search the database and then delete a record if a match is found. Then if no match is found, I would like to return an error in string format with the error message.

```
DEF INPUT PARAM i_cCarID LIKE Car.carID NO-UNDO.
DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER o_cErrorMsg AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEF BUFFER carBuffer_B1 FOR Car.


FIND FIRST carBuffer_B1 WHERE carBuffer.carID= i_cCarID EXCLUSIVE-LOCK NO-ERROR.

    IF AVAIL(carBuffer_B1) THEN DO:
        DELETE carBuffer_B1 NO-ERROR.
        IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR THEN DO:   
            o_cErrorMSG = "Error: ".
            RETURN o_cErrorMsg + ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(1).
        END.
    END.
```

This code doesn't seem to return any errors when called from java.

Edit 1. Does not finding a match even result in an error or do you have to somehow explicitly "throw" an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an output parameter but the procedure does a RETURN. That's the reason you don't see any error. Your procedure needs to be something like this: (Example has Customer table and don't have enough error handling)

```
DEF INPUT PARAM i_cCustNum LIKE Customer.Cust-Num NO-UNDO.
DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER o_cErrorMsg AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

DEF BUFFER carBuffer_B1 FOR Customer.

FIND FIRST carBuffer_B1 WHERE carBuffer_B1.Cust-Num = i_cCarID EXCLUSIVE-LOCK NO-ERROR.

IF AVAIL(carBuffer_B1) THEN 
DO:
    DELETE carBuffer_B1 NO-ERROR.
    o_cErrorMsg = "Delete Succeeded for id " + string(i_cCarID).
END.
ELSE 
DO:
    o_cErrorMsg = "No record found with id " + string(i_cCarID).
END.
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, I don't actually have to explicitly use the RETURN statement? I just rewrite the value of the output parameter and it gets sent back to the caller?

Comment: yes, you don't have to use a RETURN statement. Rewrite the output parameter and use it in the caller the way you want.